# What causes the filaments of the cosmic web to spin?

Tags: galaxy-cluster, filaments

The cosmic web is made from galaxies and dark matter  clustered together forming long thin filaments up to 80 Megaparsecs long. The filaments border voids where there is much less mass density and fewer galaxies .Our milky way is on a filament bordering a large void .

"Possible observational evidence for cosmic filament spin | Nature Astronomy" https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-021-01380-6.
"Cosmic filament spin from dark matter vortices - ScienceDirect" https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269322004324.
"Galaxy filament - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_filament